# How can I simply substitute the result of a certain require call?

Tags: node.js

I have a file path under my project folder which is often used by other modules. Currently I have to write something like this:

```
mod1 = require('../lib/mod1');

mod2 = require('./lib/modules/mod2');

mod3 = require('../../../lib/modules/mod3');
```

Can I somehow hook the require call to substitute the returned result with proper path. I am trying to achieve this:

```
mod1 = require('lib/mod1');

mod2 = require('lib/modules/mod2');

mod3 = require('lib/modules/mod3');
```

So that `lib` resolves to full path lib folder from any module inside any directory of my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is wrapping the require function according to your required usage.

```
global.myRequire= function(path) {
    return require(__dirname + '/' + path);
};
```

Add above code block in your main app.js before all required modules.

So you can call modules `var myModule = myRequire('lib/mod1');` like this.

Comment: Is there a way without wrapping the require function?

Comment: @jstice4all there is a module `app-module-path`, in your app.js `require('app-module-path').addPath(__dirname);`define path like this and then you can call your modules `mod1 = require('lib/mod1');` how you want exactly. https://github.com/patrick-steele-idem/app-module-path-node